# Proper text align with absolute position

Tags: html, css, positioning, absolute

very simple thing, but I've got lost in this ..

I have square where inside of it is heading and paragraph. What I need is simple align paragraph right under heading, but from some misterious reason there is still some space which blocks me from proper aligning. I'm using absolute positioning as you can see in code below.

Thank you soo much to get me off this! :)

SCSS

```
.wrapper-logo {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    top: 24%;
    left: 60%;

    .header-logo {
        background-image:url(../img/header.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 210px;
        height: 210px;
        margin: 8px;
        border: 0;

        h1 {
            margin: 0!important;
            padding: 80px 0 0;
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 220%;
            letter-spacing: 3px;
            color: $dark;
            font-weight: 500;
        }

        p {
            margin: 0!important;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            letter-spacing: 3px;
            word-spacing: 2px;
            color: $grey;
            line-height: 0px;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper-logo">
    <div class="header-logo">
        <h1>My heading</h1><br>
        <p>My paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it because of the `<br>` tag? That will add a line break which has a default height.

Comment: Can you quickly make a [**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com) to show the problem?

Comment: Remove `<br>` and all headings and paragraphs have some default margin clear them as well.

Comment: @SeanCogan The `<br />` is not at the end, so I assume it is not because of `<br />` but because of `<p>`'s margins?

Comment: @PraveenKumar But the issue is that the paragraph is not directly beneath the header. There is a `<br>` in between them, which will add space even if the margins on the paragraph and header are set to 0.

Comment: Yes, it's <br> tag. Ohhhh, such a simple thing, so long time wasted on css :) Thank you all of you!

Comment: @JZK No problem! Make sure you mark one of the answers as accepted for future viewers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `<br>` tag. I've set up a JSBin for you to take a look at here:

http://jsbin.com/jehijumayi/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

It was definitely the `<br>`...

```css
.wrapper-logo {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    top: 24%;
    left: 60%;
}
.header-logo {
        background-image:url(../img/header.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 210px;
        height: 210px;
        margin: 8px;
        border: 0;
}
 h1 {
            margin: 0!important;
            padding: 80px 0 0;
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 220%;
            letter-spacing: 3px;
            color: $dark;
            font-weight: 500;
        }

        p {
            margin: 0!important;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            letter-spacing: 3px;
            word-spacing: 2px;
            color: $grey;
            line-height: 0px;
        }
```

```html
        <div class="wrapper-logo">
            <div class="header-logo">
                <h1>My heading</h1>
                <p>My paragraph</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```